# android audio record schedule, service or thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I am trying to write an android app that starts a thread or a service when a button is pressed. The app will then records audio for 10 minutes in the morning and 10 minutes in the evening for 5 days in a row. There is no need for the UI to be available once the app has been started. I have been trying to do this using a service but have also tried a thread. As I am a newbie to this world of scripting, I would love some advice on which path would be best, thread or service?

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate thread to be ran inside of the service onStartCommand code.

and also reading some more tutorials would be good for you https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Thanks @Ofek Ron. Are you suggesting I should use an Intent Service? I am using the  Runnable r = new Runnable() within the public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) of the service. I am not sure how this works with an intent service?